# How to Draw Multi Line string With GeoJSON Object Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, openlayers-3, multilinestring

I am trying to draw linestring by holding the **GeoJSON** object. But when drawing process starts, the pointer can be selected everywhere on the map. My purpose is the pointer just be selected on the **GeoJSON** object

Here is some of the code.

```
var jsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kardelennkayaa/ankr_tdelay/main/KAMAN.json',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: jsonSource,
  background: 'white',
});
map.addLayer(vector)

var jsonSource_ank = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kardelennkayaa/heroku_app/main/ankara_road.json',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});

var vector_ank = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: jsonSource_ank,
  background: 'white',
});
map.addLayer(vector_ank)

var draw_lineString = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type : 'LineString',
    //source:drawSource_ls
    source:jsonSource
})
draw_lineString.on('drawstart', function(evt){
    drawSource_ls.clear()
    //select.setActive(true);
})
draw_lineString.on('drawend',function(evt){
    // alert('point is added')
    clickedCoord_lineString = evt.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
    
    $('#ls_adding').modal('show');
    console.log('clicked at', evt.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates())
    map.removeInteraction(draw_lineString)
})

function startDrawing_lineString(){
map.addInteraction(draw_lineString)
}
```

[And here is the web interface](https://minibusapp.herokuapp.com/)

The goal is when clicking on the `Add LineString`, the polyline can be drawn with the relative **GeoJSON** object. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something similar to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/tracing.html ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The link you posted is helpful, but they assumed the GeoJSON object there was a polygon. My goal here is to be able to draw over a multilinestring.